# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable ....... Python Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to execute this code. It was written in 2.x and I am changing it in python 3.7. I am able to change it and execute 90 percent of it. But I am getting a type error.

I have a file train.py

```
  import SceneDesc
  import sys

  def train(epoch):
      sd = SceneDesc.scenedesc()
      model = sd.create_model()
      batch_size = 512
      model.fit_generator(sd.data_process(batch_size=batch_size), 
      steps_per_epoch=sd.no_samples/batch_size, epochs=epoch, verbose=2, 
      callbacks=None)
      model.save('Output/Model.h5', overwrite=True)
      model.save_weights('Output/Weights.h5',overwrite=True)

  if __name__=="__main__":
      train(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

The other file is SceneDesc.py. In train.py I am calling a class scenedesc which I create in SceneDesc.py file.

```
  class scenedesc():
      def __init__(self):
          self.vocab_size = None
          self.no_samples = None
          self.max_length = None
          self.index_word = None
          self.word_index = None    
          file = open("image_encodings.p", "rb")
          self.image_encodings = pickle.load(file, encoding='bytes')
          self.captions = None
          self.img_id = None
          list(self.values())
```

While executing the train.py file. I am getting the following error:

```
   File "D:\Image-caption\Image-Captioning-master\SceneDesc.py", line 24, 
   in __init__
      list(self.values())
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Which is located in SceneDesc.py file on line   `list(self.values())`. I tried to solve it but couldn't do it. Please help me solve this error.

Comment: `list()` expects an iterable argument and it complains that _"'NoneType' object is not iterable"_, which means you passed `None` to it, which means `self.values()` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

check out the function `values()` in the class `scenedesc()` and make sure it returns something that is iterable, most likely you forgot the `return` keyword at the end of `values()`.

a good thing to know is that functions that don't have a `return` keyword, meaning that you don't explicitly code the function to return some value, it will return the value `None` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to by @zvone in the comments, the problem appears to be focused on this line and the fact that the line is not producing the values you expect:

```
list(self.values())
```

The call to `self.values()` is returning a `None` value, when `list()` want to accept some form of iterable sequence of values so that it can produce a `list`.

While this is not specifically related to your question, I am also wondering why you are converting `self.values` to a list but not saving that new value anywhere.

As written, that line will attempt to create a list in memory, but it is not getting saved anywhere for further use or processing. I would expect something like:

```py
    mylist = list(self.values())
```

Without seeing the actual code related to what `self.values()` generates, I struggle to diagnose this further. As mentioned by @isaac newton, if your `self.values()` code happens to be missing a `return` statement, Python will default to having the function return a `None` value.